# Conservation of energy violation Convection currents

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

There are three sources of heat in the Earth's core, impacts of the planet when it was created (impacts made heat), radioactive decay of elements, and the extreme amounts of pressure and friction created from rocks pressing down on each other because of gravity. The last of which creates heat only because of gravity. This is a violation of conservation of energy in my mind. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you are talking about. What's more after you edited your original question there seems to be no connection with the question posed in the title

Comment: Conservation of energy is not violated - work is done on something when it is compressed, which is converted into heat energy. Btw, your question is rather rambling and unclear.

Comment: Also note - the heat in earth's mantle is generated by radioactive decay, not friction.

Comment: ok its clear un hold me now

Comment: I would suggest removing your side question. I would vote to reopen if you did this and if you gave more detail as to why you think energy conservation is violated

Comment: fixed it yo should be good 2 go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what if instead of the crust, hypothetically, there was a layer of something, say I don't know water? and you use that to take the heat rewarm the core again

Yes, that's theoretically possible.

> and you use that to take the heat rewarm the core again and get ur earth machine cracking out more free energy for you.. Anyways in summary does the friction from convection currents in the mantle create infinite energy?

The problem is that the total energy you can harvest from this heat capture is less than the energy lost by the core.  (This is true of any heat engine).  Just heating some layer doesn't do you any good, you have do something with it to be useful.

It turns out that any method you use to extract the energy will give you less energy than the heat lost by the hot side.  So if you use it to rewarm the core, you're playing a losing game.  Eventually, the core is cold and there's no more energy to extract.

Answer (score 0):

The energy dissipated when moving down is not free, it comes from the gravitational potential energy that is being lost as it moves down. This potential energy was stored in the magma as it moved up and it came from the pressure than the surrounding magma makes to make the hot, lower density chunk go up. It is not free as you assume.

Answer (score 0):

the heat source inside the earth's core which is responsible for convection currents in the mantle is not fluid friction, it is radioactive decay of uranium and a few other radioactive elements.

Comment: thanks I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputations ;(

Answer (score 0):

This is the key to where the reasoning went wrong:

> Anyways, the now coolish mantle stuff goes down to the mantle where it rubs with more stuff creating friction and more heat- al this friction heat stuff is for free.

Putting aside that viscous losses aren't usually referred to as friction, the real problem is that **friction isn't free.** Any heat that is produced via friction is *subtracted* from the kinetic energy of the object subject to friction. As one blob of mantle rubs against another, they both slow down. Energy is conserved in this way.

> Of course the mantle stuff will repeat the process infinite times until the heat of the core is gone

The heat of the core will be gone in a **finite** time, so the mantle can only repeat this process a **finite** number of times.

> But what if instead of the crust, hypothetically, there was a layer of something, say I don't know water? and you use that to take the heat rewarm the core again and get ur earth machine cracking out more free energy for you..

First, it's impossible to completely stop the Earth from losing heat. You may be able to slow the rate of heat loss, but you cannot ever stop it completely (because the thing you use to stop it will also lose heat by radiation into the vacuum of space, among many other reasons). Therefore, the Earth's core will always lose its heat in finite time.

But let's imagine for a moment that this isn't true, that you're able, somehow, to *completely* stop the Earth from losing any heat. Then (once the radioactive decay that's currently heating the core dies out), the core is going to cool down and the crust is going to heat up so that the entire Earth eventually has a uniform temperature. This happens because, when a hot region is in contact with a cold region, heat flows from the hot region to the cold region, pushing their temperatures closer together. Here's the important part: when you have a uniform temperature, **you don't have convection anymore**. Viscous losses will eventually slow the motion of the mantle to a stop, and there won't be any temperature gradient to drive any kind of motion at that point.

You need a temperature gradient to drive convection. Once the heat sources in the core die out, you only get a temperature gradient if you're losing heat to the outside. Therefore, the motion of the mantle will only last a finite time either way.

Comment: but since there is gravity wouldn't it just speed up again after it gets frictioned? sorry what is friction in the past tense lol?

Comment: Also ever if the heat is "Lost isn't the heat created for free by the friction good, conservation of energy violating heat?

Comment: ok, I see what ur saying. But think of it this way. U got ur pan with mantle guys in it and ye got two super insulator guys that can not let ANY heat escape. You then put a warming contraption that only releases heat into the pan and nothing else. you also have a super heat guy who wants ALL the heat he can get as the lid of the pan. Those convection currents go creating heat and doing that spiny thing (who do they think they are ice skaters?) and that heat source eventually runs out of heat. Now you have quick hands also, so you use ur quick hands to replace the heater with another one of the

Comment: heat hating perfect insulator guys. After you restock your heater by using the heat from the now hot heat loving guys. Say you have 500 of these heat loving things also. You get a new, room temp one to cover the top of the pan., then you quickly put that heat loving guy back in his casing of heat hating guys so that you can keep that heat loving thing hot. You repeat process with convention current stuff and then go on until that heat loving guy is 100% exhausted and all the other 499 heat loving guys are exhausted. Anyways you see my point sort of?